# What are good, low cost, actuators for a braille tablet to be controlled by arduino?

Tags: arduino, motor, electronics

I want to basically make a pin matrix controlled either by spring, electromagnets or small motors(spring being the most viable option), something like what’s shown in the image. I'm pretty new to arduino and hardware in general so any input would be appreciated.
I mostly know the arduino end but don't have clue about the hardware part. Plus I don't have the technical expertise, as in I know electromagnets won't be a good option as I have to control individual pins and not clusters. Plus springs have the disadvantage of pushing them back in but other than that a very option. And its not viable to have individual motors for so many pins.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'spring'? Shape memory alloy actuators perhaps? (For others following this question there is a parallel question here: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11165)

Comment: @Aditya_Krishn Focused questions will get a better response. I have adjusted the question to reflect what you seem to be asking. Please verify that it is indeed what you are asking. If you can edit your question with some more detail, it will help.

Comment: You don't want to control individual pins... So you are basically looking for a mechanical matrix interface to... build a mechanical matrix interface? Apart from MEMS mirrors and some ultra-expensive ultrasound emitters, none come to mind. --- is there a specific reason you do not want to use multiplexing to interface with your matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this hackaday project. They use micro stepper motors from aliexpress. They include a link as well. The steppers are a little annoying to interface with but they are cheap and they work for this application.

https://hackaday.io/project/10849-refreshable-braille-display